# Finding duplicate tuples in a map of tuple in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I'm writing a method to find duplicate faces in a collection. The collection is of type`std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>` So, inorder to find the duplicates, I tried to create a map

```
`std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, int>` where key is tuple and value is the number of occurrences.
```

If I add the following data,

```
  std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, int> faceMap;
    faceMap[std::make_tuple(0, 1, 2)]++;
    faceMap[std::make_tuple(0, 2, 1)]++;
    faceMap[std::make_tuple(1, 0, 2)]++;
    faceMap[std::make_tuple(1, 2, 0)]++;
    faceMap[std::make_tuple(2, 1, 0)]++;
    faceMap[std::make_tuple(2, 0, 1)]++;
```

I'm expecting to get faceMap with only one key value pair in it with [0,1,2] as key and value as 6.

For sorting this, I had also tried writing a comparator as below

```
bool containsIndex(int toCheck, int i0, int i1, int i2)
{
    if (toCheck == i0 || toCheck == i1 || toCheck == i2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

struct FaceTupleComparator {
    bool operator() (const std::tuple<int, int, int>& lhs,
        const std::tuple<int, int, int>& rhs) const
    {

        auto lv0 = std::get<0>(lhs);
        auto lv1 = std::get<1>(lhs);
        auto lv2 = std::get<2>(lhs);

        auto rv0 = std::get<0>(rhs);
        auto rv1 = std::get<1>(rhs);
        auto rv2 = std::get<2>(rhs);

        bool i0Found = false, i1Found = false, i2Found = false;
        if (containsIndex(lv0, rv0, rv1, rv2))
            i0Found = true;
        if (containsIndex(lv1, rv0, rv1, rv2))
            i1Found = true;
        if (containsIndex(lv2, rv0, rv1, rv2))
            i2Found = true;


        return !(i0Found && i1Found && i2Found);
    }
};
```

and made the map as `std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, int, FaceTupleComparator> faceMap;`

it is not working for all cases where it throws exception as invalid comparator.

Can someone please help me if there is a way to find the duplicates in such a type of collection?

Comment: Maps require strict weak ordering, not equality operator. Implement `operator()` as you would `operator<`.

Comment: Please look up the requirements for a comparator for an `std::map`. You must not just ignore the requirements and hack some other functionality into it. If you try to do that, you break the data structure internally.

Comment: Instead of writing some complicated comparator, you could just sort the elements of the tuples.

Comment: Use std::unordered_map for faster performance.  And if you are just trying to find the duplicates and don't need the count, consider using std::unordered_set.

Comment: sorting might be against purpose if that's tuple representing an vertex  of 3d mesh or an element of FE (Finite Elements) mesh. I'm not sure that ordered_map or any kind of map is good use case if that's true though, for models like there are more optimal methods

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you can simple sort them before inserting in the map.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

tuple<int,int,int> additem(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int ar[3]={a,b,c};
    sort(ar,ar+3);
    return make_tuple(ar[0],ar[1],ar[2]);
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, int> faceMap;
    faceMap[additem(0,1,2)]++;
    faceMap[additem(0, 2, 1)]++;
    faceMap[additem(1, 0, 2)]++;
    faceMap[additem(1, 2, 0)]++;
    faceMap[additem(2, 1, 0)]++;
    faceMap[additem(2, 0, 1)]++;
    for(auto i:faceMap)
    {
        cout<<get<0>(i.first)<<" "<<get<1>(i.first)<<" "<<get<2>(i.first)<<" "<<i.second<<endl;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

output:

```
0 1 2 6
```

Comment: I think I like your answer better than I like mine. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: not enough for a new answer, so I'll leave it as comment here: I would use a `std::map<sorted_tuple>` where `sorted_tuple` can be implicitly converted from a `std::tuple`, then you cannot forget to call the `addItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this.  Where `vec` is your initial set of tuples you want to find duplicates from.

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> vec;  // your initial vector of tuples
```

Then a possible solution to find all the duplicates is to just convert your tuple into a string (after normalizing it into a sorted tuple).  Then use an ordered_map to track the duplicates.  And another map to go from string to reference tuple entry.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> table;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::tuple<int, int, int>> conversionMap;

for (const auto &t : vec)
{
    std::vector<int> tmp = { std::get<0>(t), std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t) };
    std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    std::string entry = std::to_string(tmp[0]) + " " + std::to_string(tmp[1]) + " " + std::to_string(tmp[2]);
    table[entry]++;
    conversionMap[entry] = t; // or std::make_tuple(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]) if you want a sorted entry
}
```

The end result of the above code is that the count of all instances of any given tuple trio is in the `table` map.  With a `conversionMap` that will map from string back to an original tuple instance.